# preg_replacе обработка ссылки :)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, replace

Приветствую.

Подскажите пожалуйста с шаблоном для реплейса...
есть ссылки :

```
/upload/blablabla/mainbla/bla/NeobyichnoeiskusstvoFingerpainting.Slon3232.jpg
/upload/blablabla/mainbla/bla1/RSRRSRRyoSSSS.png
```

нужно сделать их

```
/upload/blablabla/mainbla/bla/min/NeobyichnoeiskusstvoFingerpainting.Slon3232_min.jpg
/upload/blablabla/mainbla/bla1/min/RSRRSRRyoSSSS_min.png
```

вариант `preg_replace("/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/i","_min.\\1",$str);`
изменяет только имя файла, а как бы добавить папку min перед именем ? :)
заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/(?:\/)([^\/]+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))/i","/min/$1",$str)
```

чтобы название файла тоже меняло

```
preg_replace("/(?:\/)([^\/]+)(\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))/i","/min/$1_min$2",$str)
```

Comment: спасибо круто) но в этом варианте подставляется только папка перед именем файла. а само имя не меняется :)

Comment: @Jenyok добавил в ответ

Comment: @Jenyok если у вас одна точка только в расширение то можно и так `str_replace('.','_min.',$str)`